# Reverso web site speaks too fast

Tags: online-learning, translation

Reverso has a play feature that plays a voice saying the selected text.  I am using this for learning Russian but find that the playback speaks so fast as to be useless.  Is there a way to slow it down?

Comment: Have you tried to contact their support service?